How to stop an ffmpeg job when -nosdtin is enabled?
I use Python to run an FFMPEG command using subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd). 
My project needs to pause/resume the ffmpeg job for a while. 
To do so, I use process.suspend() and process.resume() from the psutils library.
However, when I resume the process, FFMPEG asks me some inputs :
Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
I have found that adding the flag -nosdtin in my ffmpeg command avoid the issue.
But now, I don't know how to stop the process since the stdin is disabled. 
I tried :
process.send_signal(subprocess.signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) // with no effect
process.terminate() // ends the process but loses the job done


Instead of adding -nosdtin, avoid using shell=True when opening FFmpeg subprocess.
Python code sample:
import subprocess as sp
import shlex
import psutil
from time import sleep

# Open FFmpeg subprocess with opened stdin pipe (generate synthetic pattern for testing):
process = sp.Popen(shlex.split('ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4'), stdin=sp.PIPE)
ps_process = psutil.Process(pid=process.pid)  # Pass the PID of FFmpeg subprocess to PsUtil.

sleep(3)  # Wait 3 seconds for testing ("recored 3 seconds")
ps_process.suspend()  # Suspend FFmpeg process for 3 seconds
sleep(3)  # Wait 3 seconds
ps_process.resume()  # Resume FFmpeg process.
sleep(3)
ps_process.suspend()
sleep(3)
ps_process.resume()

# Close FFmpeg gracefully:
process.stdin.write(b'q')  # Simulate user pressing q key for gracefully closing FFmpeg.
process.communicate()
process.wait()


In Linux, when using: process = sp.Popen(shlex.split('ffmpeg ...'), stdin=sp.PIPE, shell=True), I am getting the following message usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}... and Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'.

I'm not sure of the usefulness of the psutils library here, but I do have a script working with standard libraries that'll send SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals to the process group spawned by the ffmpeg command:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time
import os

ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -i /tmp/in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 /tmp/out.mp4"

process = subprocess.Popen(
        ffmpeg_cmd,
        shell=True,
        preexec_fn=os.setsid,
        stdout= open(os.devnull, 'w'),
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

while True:
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), subprocess.signal.SIGSTOP)
    print("asleep")
    time.sleep(10)
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), subprocess.signal.SIGCONT)
    print("awake")
    time.sleep(5)

Example output is:
$ ./test.py 
asleep
awake
asleep
awake
asleep
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/preston/superuser/1856303/./test.py", line 19, in <module>
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
$ 

You can see the work starting and stopping in a resource monitor:

